# How to compute k nearest neighbors and their indices in python

Tags: python

I have this matrix of size NxM.

```
X = np.random.randn(200, 20)
ids = [_ in range(200)]
```

I am trying to write a function which takes X, ids and k as an input and returns top k ids based on nearest neigbors

```
def compute_nearest_ids(X, ids, k):

   return some_ids[:k]
```

To compute this, I thought if only I can get the indices of nearest neighbors, I can probably just slice those indices from ids.
What's a good/pythonic way to solve this.?

Comment: How do you define the distance between two elements in a matrix?

Comment: @pokfungChan cosine distance

Comment: What is the array ids representing?

Comment: @pokfungChan think of them as some identifiers. In the example above, they are simply numbers. 
But what I am interested in is "which ids are closest" rather than the distances.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example, e.g. a 2x2 matrix and the expected outcome because I still found ids confusing. I don't understand why it has a size of 200.